# Would this question be appropriate for MathOverflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic, math-stackexchange

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3491953/reflection-groups-of-division-rings) in Math Stack Exchange several days ago, but I have received no interaction so far, apart from 4 upvotes. I was considering adding a bounty, but since (to my humble understanding) the question seems to be of research level, I was wondering if it would be appropriate to post it here instead after a week or two, in the case that I get no feedback in MSE during that time.

Of course I would reword the question to make it more concise, and perhaps modify its scope to avoid duplication of content.

Around eight months ago I did a similar thing with another question ([MSE version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3203167/which-root-lattices-have-a-theta-series-with-this-property), [MO version](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333086/which-even-lattices-have-a-theta-series-with-this-property)). The question turned out to be well-received here and had a helpful answer. But I think this case is different, because it is about a generalization that I haven't seen even mentioned in the literature I've checked, and since I'm not a professional mathematician (my background is in physics) I don't have the knowledge to discern whether it's because it has a trivial answer, because it is too broad to answer or even if the question is ill-posed.

> Is my question suitable for MathOverflow in its current state? If not, are there any modification(s) I could make so that it becomes suitable?

---

**EDIT:** Thank you all for your help! The question is now posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349809/is-there-a-classification-of-reflection-groups-over-division-rings).

Comment: Since I am not expert enough to judge quality of this one, I say wait a couple days or more for an informed response on meta. Worst case scenario is that you post it next week on MathOverflow with a link to here, it gets closed for some unfathomable reason, and you did due diligence.  If you do post it, include about half or less of the math.stackexchange material below the question, and link to the other version.  If regulars want to see the other stuff on the MathOverflow version, they'll let you know. Gerhard "Make Them Ask For It" Paseman, 2020.01.02.

Comment: When posting on MO do not forget that it is recommended that *all* copies/versions of the post should be linked to the other ones. See: [Cross posts to Math SE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2637#2638).

Comment: We had [a similar request](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4401/is-my-question-suitable-for-mo) recently here. Possibly a generic Q&A would be useful, or possibly a single multiple-answer question where each answer would address a specific question?

Comment: @YCor In other site I used a [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions), which is a single meta post where newer users post prospective questions and more experienced users sometimes browse by and leave feedback in comments; perhaps something like that could work for MathOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a problem.  I suggest you change the title to a question, like "Is there a classification of reflection groups over division rings?" or "Is there a division ring analogue of the Shepard-Todd theorem?"